# How can I make complex Gremlin queries in AWS Neptune without variables?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I'm using Amazon Neptune, which [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#w3aac15c18c10c15c37) variables. For complex queries, however, I need to use a variable in multiple places. How can I do this without querying twice for the same data?

Here's the problem I'm trying to tackle:

> Given a start `Person`, find `Persons` that the start `Person` is connected to by at most 3 steps via the `knows` relationship. Return each `Person`'s `name` and `email`, as well as the `distance` (1-3).

How would I write this query in Gremlin without variables, since variables are unsupported in Neptune?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you would need variables for your traversal and there are many ways you could get an answer. Assuming this graph:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('person').property('name','A').property('age',20).as('a').
  addV('person').property('name','B').property('age',21).as('b').
  addV('person').property('name','C').property('age',22).as('c').
  addV('person').property('name','D').property('age',19).as('d').
  addV('person').property('name','E').property('age',22).as('e').
  addV('person').property('name','F').property('age',24).as('f').
  addE('next').from('a').to('b').
  addE('next').from('b').to('c').
  addE('next').from('b').to('d').
  addE('next').from('c').to('e').
  addE('next').from('d').to('e').
  addE('next').from('e').to('f').iterate()
```

You could do something like:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','A').
......1>   repeat(out().
......2>          group('m').
......3>            by(loops()).
......4>            by(valueMap('name','age').by(unfold()).fold())).
......5>     times(3).
......6>   cap('m')
==>[0:[[name:B,age:21]],1:[[name:C,age:22],[name:D,age:19]],2:[[name:E,age:22],[name:E,age:22]]]
```

Find a particular "person" vertex by their name, in this case "A", then repeatedly traverse `out()` and group those vertices you come across by `loops()` which is how deep you have traversed. I use `valueMap()` in this case to extract the properties you wanted. The `times(3)` is the limit to the depth of your search. Finally you `cap()` out the side-effect `Map` held in "m" from our `group()`. That approach was meant to just give you a bit of basic structure to how you would accomplish this. You could perhaps polish it further this way:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','A').
......1>   repeat(out().
......2>          group('m').
......3>            by(loops())).
......4>     times(3).
......5>   cap('m').unfold().select(values).unfold().
......6>   dedup().
......7>   valueMap('name','age').by(unfold())
==>[name:B,age:21]
==>[name:C,age:22]
==>[name:D,age:19]
==>[name:E,age:22]
```

The above example, extracts the values from the `Map` in "m", removes the duplicates with `dedup()` and then converts to the result you want. Maybe you don't need the `Map` in the first place (I just have it on my mind because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048029/1831717) actually) - you could simple `store()` your results as follows:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','A').
......1>   repeat(out().store('m')).
......2>     times(3).
......3>   cap('m').unfold().
......4>   dedup().
......5>   valueMap('name','age').by(unfold())
==>[name:B,age:21]
==>[name:C,age:22]
==>[name:D,age:19]
==>[name:E,age:22]
```

You might look at using something like `simplePath()` as well to help avoid re-traversing the same paths over and over again. You can read about that step in the [Reference Documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#simplepath-step).